# How can I conditionally skip a parameterized pytest scenario?

Tags: pytest

I need to flag certain tests to be skipped. However, some of the tests are parameterized and I need to be able to skip only certain of the scenarios.

I invoke the test using `py.test -m "hermes_only"` or `py.test -m "not hermes_only"` as appropriate.

Simple testcases are marked using:

```py
@pytest.mark.hermes_only
def test_blah_with_hermes(self):
```

However, I have some parameterized tests:

```py
outfile_scenarios = [('buildHermes'),
                     ('buildTrinity')]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('prefix', outfile_scenarios)
def test_blah_build(self, prefix):
    self._activator(prefix=prefix)
```

I would like a mechanism to filter the scenario list or otherwise skip certain tests if a pytest mark is defined.

More generally, how can I test for the definition of a pytest mark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Updated answer: With newer versions of python, it is now necessary to use the pattern described by @Migwell]

The documentation cited by @Migwell uses `skipif` but if you want to use a custom mark defined elsewhere, here is an updated version of my previous example:

```py
import pytest

scenarios = [pytest.param('trinity', 'buildTrinity',
                          marks=pytest.mark.trinity_only),
             pytest.param('legacy',  'buildLegacy',
                          marks=pytest.mark.legacy_only)]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('tcid, prefix', scenarios,
                         ids=[id[0] for id in scenarios])
def test_sample(self, tcid, prefix):
    pass
```

Additionally, custom marks should be registered to avoid `PytestUknownMarkWarning` complaints. In `conftest.py`, add the following:

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "trinity_only: Runs trinity_only tests.")
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "legacy_only: Runs legacy_only tests.")
```

Alternatively, they can be registered in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    trinity_only: Runs trinity_only tests.
    legacy_only: Runs legacy_only tests.
```

Custom marks are used by using pytest's `-m` option. For example,  `pytest -m trinity_only`

I hope this addresses your problem with my original answer @adam-hoelscher

Comment: I'm not able to recreate a minimal example here. I have no logic in place to actually skip the tests, but the marked one won't even run. What needs to change in this file?
https://gist.github.com/Adam-Hoelscher/b60ddb57915b5eca5dc16f3f0ff965da

Answer (score 23):

A nice solution [from the documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skip-xfail-with-parametrize) is this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("n", "expected"),
    [   
        (1, 2), 
        pytest.param(1, 0, marks=pytest.mark.xfail),
        pytest.param(1, 3, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="some bug")),
        (2, 3), 
        (3, 4), 
        (4, 5), 
        pytest.param(
            10, 11, marks=pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info >= (3, 0), reason="py2k")
        ),  
    ],  
)
def test_increment(n, expected):
    assert n + 1 == expected
```